# Display Summary View of datatable

Tags: apex, visualforce

We want to summarize the Product Column like the second table because I am using apex:repeat 
[image]

Controller code:

```
Assignments = [Select id,name, pse__Role__c, pse__Resource__c,pse__Planned_Hours__c 
               from pse__Assignment__c 
               where pse__Project__c=:sr.Project__c];

for(pse__Assignment__c a :Assignments) {
    mapAssign.put((String)a.pse__Role__c,a);
}

public  Set<String> mapgetkyset() {
    return mapAssign.keyset();
}

public List<pse__Assignment__c> mapgetvalues(String role) {
    List<pse__Assignment__c> lstassgn = new List<pse__Assignment__c>();
    for (pse__Assignment__c  assgn : mapAssign.values()) {
         if(assign.pse__Role__c==role) {
             lstassgn.add(assgn);
    }
    return lstassgn;
}
```

Vf page:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 1em;font-size:18px">
    <b>Budget Summaries</b>
</div>
<br/>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">Role</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">Resource</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">Hours</td>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="mapgetkyset()" var="Assig">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">{!Assig.pse__Role__c}</td>
            <td>
                Assig
                <apex:repeat value="mapgetvalues()" var="a">
                    <apex:param assignTo="role" value="Assig">
                    <tr>
                        <td>style="text-align:center">{!a.Asspse__Resource__c}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{!a.pse__Planned_Hours__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                 </apex:repeat>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: That is easy. You need to create map, that has list of records as value, and product as key in apex code, and then do apex:repeat two times -- per entire map and per list for each key in map

Comment: or in case of ordinary array -- sort it by group, and create vf variable, that store previous shown product, so in case if previous shown product and current one are same -- do not show it

Comment: can you please help me here with some code

Comment: we have a custom object not an ordinary array.

Comment: if you post what you already have -- it would be easier

Comment: Controller code :

Comment: Posted code below...

Answer (score 0):

Controller code:

```
Assignments = [Select id,name, pse__Role__c, pse__Resource__c,pse__Planned_Hours__c from pse__Assignment__c where pse__Project__c=:sr.Project__c];


for(pse__Assignment__c a :Assignments){
     mapAssign.put((String)a.pse__Role__c,a);
}

public  Set<String> mapgetkyset(){
     return mapAssign.keyset();
}

public  List<pse__Assignment__c> mapgetvalues(String role){

            List<pse__Assignment__c> lstassgn = new List<pse__Assignment__c>();

            for (pse__Assignment__c  assgn : mapAssign.values()){
                 if(assign.pse__Role__c==role){
                     lstassgn.add(assgn);
                 }

             }
            return lstassgn;

}
```

Vf page:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 1em;font-size:18px"><b>Budget Summaries</b></div>
      <br/>
      <table border="1">
      <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">Role</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">Resource</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">Hours</td>
      </tr>

      <apex:repeat value="mapgetkyset()" var="Assig">
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center">{!Assig.pse__Role__c}</td>
          <td>Assig
                <apex:repeat value="mapgetvalues()" var="a"><apex:param assignTo="role" value="Assig">
              <tr>
                  <td>style="text-align:center">{!a.Asspse__Resource__c}</td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">{!a.pse__Planned_Hours__c}</td>
              </tr>
               </apex:repeat>

          </td>
      </tr>
      </apex:repeat>
      </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Screen Shot:

[image: below image is my requirement]

Trying to group by role. I am unable to achieve it using maps